# Is it possible to implement an abstraction like the repository pattern using Javascript specifically using Javascript with Node

Tags: javascript, repository-pattern

I've been using Javascript for years on the front-end. I didn't care about learning the engineering of it as my usage is very basic. Now I am using node on the backend and, given the requirements of the backend, it requires more knowledge and technical considerations. Considering the nature of Javascript, are abstractions achieved normally, more specifically the repository pattern that provides access to a database. Which language components would I use since Javascript doesn't have interfaces? A snippet that returns a user through the repository pipeline would be good.

Comment: Use TypeScript and you can have as many interfaces as you want. (Personally, if I was writing any Node app I'd do it in TypeScript.)

Comment: found a [javascript example](https://dev.to/thanasismpalatsoukas/repository-pattern-with-javascript-4nl)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use existing JS DI libraries or use the module system to manage youre repositories and DI:

```
// repositories/UserRepositoryInterface.ts
export interface UserRepositoryInterface {
  
  getUser(id: string): Promise<[User | null | undefined, Error | undefined>;

}

// repositories/WhateverDbUserRepostory .ts
export class WhateverDbUserRepostory implements UserRepositoryInterface {
  getUser(id: string): Promise<[User | null | undefined, Error | undefined> {
    // ...
  }
}

// repositories/index.ts
export const repository = new WhateverDbUserRepostory();

// app/index.ts
import {repository} from "../repositories";

repository.getUser().then(([user, error]) => {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  // User not found
  if (user === null) return;
  console.log(user?.username);
});
```

It works the same way in JS without the interfaces.
You could also only export classes but then constructor has to be the same or use factories if you dont want singletons.